# Initializing GMSMapView crash

Tags: swift, google-maps

[image][image]My program crashes on initializing GMSMapView object.
For example:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
let store = Store.default
let map: GMSMapView = GMSMapView()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    guard GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppConstants.Keys.googleMaps.rawValue) else { fatalError("Can not initialize Google Map services") }

    print("Map: \(self.map)")

    return true
}
```

On initializing GMSMapView, the code reports the following:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what 'crashes' means? Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when I run program

Comment: what was the fix for this. after 4y and 6m I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
let store = Store.default
var map: GMSMapView?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    guard GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppConstants.Keys.googleMaps.rawValue) else { fatalError("Can not initialize Google Map services") }
    self.map = GMSMapView()
    print("Map: \(self.map)")

    return true
}
```

try to change it like this

Comment: could you provide screenshot where error will be visible?

Answer (score 0):

Check the console output. You should see the following error:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use`

You are trying to initialize the mapView before `GMSService.provideAPIKey`

Comment: Console output:

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Nope, Google Maps initialized properly, I have no idea why can't create GMSMapView

Answer (score 0):

### Follow this steps:

**Step 1:** Add your API key to your `AppDelegate.swift` as follows:

1. Add the following import statement:

```
import GoogleMaps
```

2. Add the following to your `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method, using your API key:

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

**Step 2:** Add a map:

1. Add methods in your app's default `ViewController` to create and initialize an instance of `GMSMapView`.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var mapView: GMSMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.frame, camera: camera)
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
  }
}
```

2. Run the app.

---

### Alternative solution:

Make changes in the existing code in the `appDelegate.swift`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
let store = Store.default
let map: GMSMapView!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppConstants.Keys.googleMaps.rawValue)
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    map = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.frame)
    // map object is ready to use
    print(map)
    return true
}
```

Unknown `width` & `height` are the device screen dimensions.